# node.js, express.js and mongodb problem while connecting two schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Login and register is successfully working, after loggedin user1 can enter their profile details and details is displayed in that page. the problem if user2 is loggedin he can see user1 profile details means it is not storing profile details under that userid.

user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/pms2', {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

var conn =mongoose.Collection;
var userSchema =new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type:String, 
        required: true,
        index: {
            unique: true,        
        }},

    email: {
        type:String, 
        required: true,
        index: {
            unique: true, 
        },},
    password: {
        type:String, 
        required: true
    },
    date:{
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now }
});

var userModel = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
module.exports=userModel;
```

profile.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/pms2', {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

var conn =mongoose.Collection;
var profileSchema =new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {type:String, 
        required: true,
        index: {
            unique: true,        
        }},

    lastname: {
        type:String, 
        required: true,
        index: {
            unique: true, 
        },},
    address: {
        type:String, 
        required: true,
        index: {
            unique: true,        
        }},
        phonenumber: {
            type:parseInt, 
            required: true,
            index: {
                unique: true,        
            }},
    date:{
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now }
});

var profileModel = mongoose.model('profile', profileSchema);
module.exports=profileModel;
```

Comment: I think you dont need two schemas, don´t use 'new' : var profileSchema = mongoose.Schema(), and module.exports = mongoose.model("profile", profileSchema);

Comment: The code in the question doesn't demonstrate the problem.  Can you add some example code that shows the problem occurring?